# A loop to add each item in a list to a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am taking some inputs from a json file and adding them to a list. 
For each item in the list (ProjectList) it pings an API and brings back some info from it.

The code is like this

```
with open('filewatcherConfig2.json', 'r') as json_file:
    source = json.load(json_file)

ProjectList = []
for ProjectName in source:
    ProjectList.append(ProjectName)

#account_create = "curl -v -f https://www.{}.com/{}".format(ProjectList[0], ProjectList[0])

curls = []
for i in ProjectList:
    account_create = "curl -v -f https://www.{}.com/{}".format(ProjectList[0], ProjectList[1])
print(curls)
```

The var account_create comes back with exactly the right thing i am expecting but how do i add that into a loop for however many items are in the original list?
I am expecting the output of `print(curls)` to be a list of curl commands for each project in the original list but it comes back empty.

Comment: Are you sure `account_create` is exactly what you want? it never changes. And what is the issue exactly? adding it to `curls` list?

Comment: To add that to `curls` you would use `curls.append(account_create)` below the creation of `account_create`. But it seems like your `account_create` is always same as you pass static values in it instead of using `i` to do different stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append `account_create` to `curls` in each iteration of the loop. The bigger issue is the content of `account_create`, it never changes. You need to iterate over `ProjectList` items, not index

```
curls = []
for p in project_list:
    curls.append("curl -v -f https://www.{}.com/{}".format(p, p))
```

Or with list comprehensions and f-string (if you use Python 3.6 or newer)

```
project_list = [name for name in source]
curls = [f"curl -v -f https://www.{p}.com/{p}" for p in project_list]
```

*`ProjectList` should be named `project_list`

Comment: This only gives one curl command as the output. 
If the original list is a list like this ['apples', 'oranges', 'pears', 'bananas']
My expected output would be 

`
curl -v -f https://www.apples.com/apples

curl -v -f https://www.oranges.com/oranges

curl -v -f https://www.pears.com/pears

curl -v -f https://www.bananas.com/bananas
`

Comment: @Alex Update my answer